# Mapping urls to states that dont exist

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am using [ui-router-extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/) extensively but still not sure if I am getting the most out of it . I have used `Future States` to build the routes in runtime after retrieving from the `API` . I am trying to solve a case , where `ui-tabs` dynamically created with the data in the controller , and I need to create states for them when the tabs are created .

Just so that , hitting , `/tabs/` that has tabs but nothing selected should create the states and , hitting `/tabs/1` should show the first tab.

I tried to implement this by creating the states in the controller , but hitting `/tabs/1` does not activate the tab but instead redirects to the default url because the state is not created yet .

Any help appreciated .